# Compile-time error 450 on accessing the default member of a collection

Tags: excel, vba

**Edit:** Please note that I am aware this code will fail at run-time. I kept it as short as possible for the demonstration of the issue.

Consider this VBA class module "TestClass":

```
Option Explicit
Public TestCol As New Collection
```

In a standard module, this won't compile:

```
Sub Test()
Dim Smth As New TestClass
Smth.TestCol(1) = "Something"
End Sub
```

**Error message given:** "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

This will compile just fine:

```
Sub Test()
Dim Smth As New TestClass
Smth.TestCol.Item(1) = "Something"
End Sub
```

This will also compile fine:

```
Sub Test()
Dim Smth As New TestClass
Dim X as String
X = Smth.TestCol(1)
End Sub
```

It's the same with e. g. dictionaries.
Why will the compiler not allow access to the default member `.Item` without explicitly stating it?

Comment: Is your question just why you get a compile error in the first snippet, vs. run-time error in the next two?

Comment: Just the compile error. I know the code is not functional at run-time, I just tried to keep it as short as possible for the demonstration of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Items in a Collection are primarily objects, even though the value of the Item is a Variant and may contain any type.

The following code will not cause a compile error because it uses the Set keyword to assign an object.

```
Sub Test()
   Dim Smth As New TestClass
   Set Smth.TestCol(1) = New TestClass
End Sub
```

However, this code will fail at runtime because you cannot assign to an Item in a Collection directly. (Use Remove+Add instead.)

Comment: I am not trying to assign an object, but a string. Even though it will fail at runtime for the very reason you mentioned, it's supposed to compile. But it doesn't and I'm trying to figure out why. Also, this is only an issue with collections. A dictionary allows direct assignment to a key, but the compiler won't allow it either.